# How to add additional headers to 302 redirects in Apache?

Tags: apache, redirect, cdn, http-status-code-302

I have a redirect in Apache config like

Redirect temp   /foo.xml     http://www.baz.com/foo.xml

I am trying to add an Expire and m-cache headers for a CDN to this 302. This would be trivial in php, but I need to do this in Apache config files.

Normally this is done like this:

ExpiresActive On
   ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 minutes"

but this only seems to not work for 302 redirects. Any suggestions?

Comment: Apache configuration? Via which programming language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the mod_headers module for Apache.

Perhaps something like:

```
<Location /foo.xml>
   Redirect temp /foo.xml http://www.baz.com/foo.xml
   Header always set ExpiresActive On
   Header always set ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 minutes"
</Location>
```

I have edited this answer (since it was accepted), adding the **always** keyword, to reflect what Fix correctly pointed out below.

Comment: Except, this doesn't actually work because the headers aren't added when a redirect is done.

Comment: This does work because of the `always` directive.. See @Fix's answer below. it explains it better.

Answer (score 17):

```
<Location /foo.xml>
   Redirect temp /foo.xml http://www.baz.com/foo.xml
   Header always set ExpiresActive On
   Header always set ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 minutes"
</Location>
```

to get it working even with HTTP 302 responses (actually, with any HTTP response) ;
without the keyword "**always**", the directive "Header set" works only with success responses, i.e. HTTP 2xx responses.

Answer (score 4):

Please note an odd bug in Apache 2.2 (observed in Apache 2.2.15) that makes this difficult if you are using `env=HTTPS` to control when the Header is being set.  For some reason `env=HTTPS` fails to fire during redirects, even if `RewriteCond %{HTTPS}` on is used to control the redirect.  So in my configuration that enables HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS), I use use a RewriteRule to create an environment variable called `X_HTTPS` that has the same value as the `HTTPS`, but which is not set to null when `env=X_HTTPS` is evaluated:

```
SetEnv HSTS "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"

# For some reason in Apache 2.2, HTTPS env variable is not available during redirects
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [ENV=X_HTTPS:%{HTTPS}]
# Set HSTS Header if the page is delivered via SSL
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security %{HSTS}e env=X_HTTPS

# Redirect SSL-only non-www page to www and quit
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=303,L]

# Redirect ANY non-SSL page to SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=303,L]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do. Unfortunately this solution doesn't work for me. No environment variables seem to work with redirects. The only solution I've found is to omit the `env=` clause, which works but also sends the Strict-Transport-Security header on plain HTTP requests.