# When doing a 301 redirect, who's the UserAgent?

Tags: php, laravel, user-agent, referrer

[php.net specifies that](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

> 'HTTP_REFERER' The address of the page (if any) which referred the
>   user agent to the current page. ***This is set by the user agent.*** Not all
>   user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify
>   HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

**My question is** if the redirect is happening on the server level, who's considered the UserAgent? and how do i make sure referrer info is sent with a 301?

**ex.**
i have page mywebsite1.com/page, which i 301Redirect to mywebsite2.com/page 
now when it goes to my mywebsite2.com/page, i cant see no referrer info, and im wondering who sets this info!

Comment: The web browser (usually).

Comment: The user agent is the browser in most cases. The browser is free to send or to omit the referer header.

Comment: How 'bout trying?

Comment: Say you were using cURL. It would be something like `User-Agent: curl/7.37.0`. Just dump the headers and you will see exactly what is in them.

Comment: To clarify, the redirect **does not happen at server level**. The server sends a redirect **response** asking the user agent (whatever accessed the page) to follow that redirect. The user agent *might* follow it and it also *might* send a referer header when requesting the new page.

Comment: Press F12 and check your network tab for network activity. You can persist the logs so that you do not lose sight of pages loaded in between redirects and this will allow you to check their headers and see exactly what is being sent back and forth.

Comment: @ggdx well i tried to dump the User_agent, and apparently the UserAgent is carried out with the redirect. which is a bit weird in my case.. cause i wanna know the previous Request and thats all.

Comment: @apokryfos oh i see, then the userAgent (browser in mycase) decides that it will stick to the first referrer and continue the request?
hmmm...

Comment: @AbdRmdn Maybe, every web browser can behave differently.

Comment: i see.. thanks, this was useful

Answer (score 4):

The "user agent" is the client sending HTTP requests to an HTTP server. In most cases, the user agent is a web browser, but the term is more general to include things like automated scripts.

The key misunderstanding in your question is that a redirect doesn't "happen on the server level". What happens is this:

1. The user agent sends an HTTP request to the server for a URL.
2. The server responds with an HTTP response, with the "status" line set to "301" (or one of the other "redirect" statuses), and a "Location" header containing a new URL.
3. The user agent *probably* sends a second request to the server, for the new URL.
4. The server receives the second request *and has no way of knowing if it was connected with the first request*.

The "referer" header (the misspelling is historical, and now officially "correct") is just part of the information sent by the user agent *with each request*. (Importantly, like everything in the request, it cannot be trusted for any kind of security purpose, because someone can write a request with any value they want.)

The [RFC section on the Referer header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.5.2) doesn't specify its behaviour very closely, and I can find no reference there to how it should be populated after a redirect response. As such, different user agents may behave differently, and you would need to test in different browsers to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Relying on referrer alone is not reliable at all, since browsers can omit providing that, depending on the user's privacy settings, installed plugins or even browser settings.

The best way to detect users coming from your redirect is just redirecting them to something like `mywebsite2.com/page?redirected_from=mywebsite1`, and look for that query string on your page located on `mywebsite2.com`.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The User Agent is whatever entity is making the HTTP requests, it may be a browser, an internal library used by a server application which acts as a client and makes requests, a proxy server forwarding requests to other address or services.

There is no guarantee that referrer will be forwarded to the destination server. In a proxy for example you have to instruct it to forward the referrer header to the destination server (often at configuration level). In a similar manner you should check that the whoever is responsible for handling the redirect forwards the referrer header to the following request (the destination of the redirect).

If you are using Guzzle to handle the redirects then you should look to [Guzzle docs](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#allow-redirects) to automatically add the header to the requests.
If Apache is responsible to handle the redirects you should intervene to set the header within the webserver configuration, in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4186041/455883) you can find a way to set Headers programmatically while redirecting.

Comment: That linked answer about adding headers in Apache is about adding headers to the *response*, whereas this question is about a header in the *request*. Except when it's used as a proxy, Apache doesn't act as the *client*, so would not be creating HTTP requests.

Comment: I was trying to answer to this part of question: "and how do i make sure referrer info is sent with a 301?". I saw the PHP and Laravel tags so I assumed the most common environment (Guzzle as PHP HTTPClient and Apache as a webserver).

Comment: A request made using Guzzle will have whatever header that library sets, or what the PHP script tells it to set; adding `Header` lines in an Apache configuration file will have no effect on that whatsoever. (Imagine if it did: it would mean that *every single request* made by that PHP script would include the same header; that wouldn't be very useful.)